# Spring for android: How to parse Json objects with different parameters

Tags: android, json, spring

I got following Json:

```
"geometries": [
                {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                4.8979805,
                                52.3798389
                            ],
                            [
                                4.8982922,
                                52.3801447
                            ],
                            [
                                4.9027811,
                                52.378504
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        4.7622823,
                        52.3095072
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                4.4665891,
                                51.9253793
                            ],
                            [
                                4.4700603,
                                51.926059
                            ],
                            [
                                4.4707517,
                                51.9247593
                            ],
                            [
                                4.4706054,
                                51.9247303
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Which can have `Polygons` and `Points`. I am using spring for android to parse the Json.
But because the `geometries` have different `coordinates` types (array of array of array of double OR just array of double), I am  not sure how to do this.

Json if from external source, so cant do much about it.

Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define coordinates as; `List<Object> coordinates;` after just before using the coordinates (i.e in the getter method) you can check whether you post-process it and in the post process you can do any further.

i guess this will help you

```
class MyClass {
    Geometry geometries[];

    Geometry[] getGeometries() {
        return geometries;
    }

    void setGeometries(Geometry[] geometries) {
        this.geometries = geometries;
    }
}
class Geometry {
    String type;
    List<Object> coordinates;

    String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    List<Object> getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates; // you can simply return something more advanced such like List<CoordinateInterface> 
    }

    void setCoordinates(List<Object> coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
}
```

Comment: consider having a better username :) ppl don't like answering nomads here :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is the second question I asked here, I usually get my answers from other questions answered here so I havnt really thought about changing my username.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of value associated with key `coordinates`

And depending on the type of the value, you can decide the behavior.

You can check type using `instanceof`

So in your case, you can check like this->

```
if(object instanceof List) {
 //Array of Array of Array of Double
} else if(object instance of Map) {
 //Array of Double   
}
```

You can use this code -

```
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = gson.formJson(jsonStr, Map.class);
List<Map<String, Object>> list = jsonMap.get("geometries");
foreach(Map<String, Object> map : list) {
 List<Object> objList = map.get("coordinates");
 foreach(Object obj : objList) {
  if(obj instanceof List) {
   //obj is Array of Double
  } else if(obj instace of Double){
   //obj is Double/Actual value
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The coordinates key is a String value.
I know how to use the instanceof, the problem is that Spring checks for the variable name and then puts the value in the right one.
I dont know how to fix it with 2 different types with the same name.
So I need to know how i can tell Spring to connect the right type to the coordinates variable

Comment: What you mean by using Spring for Android for parsing JSON? Are you using Jackson to parse JSON?

Comment: http://www.springsource.org/spring-android its a library to parse Json on Android. Im using Gson to parse the Json, well Spring is...

Comment: Is it solving the problem?

Comment: I used the other solution, was easyer to implement with spring for android. Thanks anyway!